# Do something after clicking alert ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do something like this?

```
alert('Im gonna get you!');
$('#some-id').css({"display": "none"});
```

OR

```
alert('Im gonna get you!');
$('#some-id').trigger('click');
```

I thought anything that's called after alert() will be executed after clicking ok?

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you set up a non working example for us, as I sure can't as that works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking at. But it seems to me that the alert function is blocking, execution doesn't continue until the user clicks ok.
Try running your own code, or [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=uSCp4KvzcP) and see it in action!

Comment: I did not provide a previous answer. Someone else did, but they took it down, probably they realized it wasn't applicable or something along those lines.

Comment: Thought it was you. But it was working whoever that was.

Comment: As we pointed out, your own code works. The answer that got deleted was for a confirm function.

Comment: mason, yeah my answer was wrong, that's why I deleted it, just thought of things weirdly :). @joejam the answer you saw was if(confirm("I'm going to get you")){ $('#some-id').css({"display": "none"});} don't know why the person who posted, deleted it.